# Need a mandatory condition in subject before testing regex in body

Tags: if-statement, sieve

I am a new dev in SIEVE and I am trying to create a filter in Thunderbird with two conditions. sorry if the question is dumb

- first: Subject must match a specific string ([SUPPORT])
- second : if some terms are present flagged the email in question.

I have tried first with nested if but it do not work. After several tries I have this script :

```
require ["body","imap4flags", "regex"];
# rule:[RT QA]

if not header :contains "subject" "[SUPPORT]"
{
keep ;
 }
 elsif body :regex ["pay.*impossible|impossible.*pay","/b+u+g+/","login.*impossible|impossible.*login"]
{ 
    addflag "$label1";
}
```

but do not seem to work either . Any idea / lead welcomed